# excluding multiple mysql rows in php

Tags: php, mysql

I'm using this code to exclude checkout_success, checkout_without_account, and index and many more i want to add, but I don't want to keep adding "and page_alias != "***" everytime I want to exclude something. THis method works but Isn't there a more concise and cleaner way to exclude multiple rows in this != format without having to repeat so much code?

```
$page_query = tep_db_query('select * from ' . TABLE_INFORMATION . ' where languages_id="' . (int)$languages_id . '" and visible=1 and page_alias != "index" and page_alias != "checkout_without_account" and page_alias != "checkout_success" order by v_order asc') ;
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

"Not in" should fix it:

```
Where fieldname NOT IN ('value1', 'value2', 'value3');
```

Answer (score 0):

Use the `IN` syntax:

```
WHERE page_alias NOT IN ('checkout_without_account', 'checkout_success', 'foo', 'bar', 'baz', ....)
```